# Change path for Spring Cloud Config

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

We are currently running a [Spring Cloud Config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) instance but would like to change the path where the server exposes the configuration.

What we have today:
`http://{server.url}:{server:port}/{app.name}/{app.profile}..`
What we would like:
`http://{server.url}:{server:port}/custom path/{app.name}/{app.profile}..`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_embedding_the_config_server).
In the application config file (yml/properties) the property `spring.cloud.config.server.prefix` needs to be set to the path you want to assign